# Ensuring a paramterized type has particular method

Tags: java, type-parameter

How can I specify that a particular parametrized type needs to have a particular method?

What I mean is:  If I have my class `public class SparseMatrix<type>`, and one of my methods in the class (the `add` method) needs to use the add method of its members, how can I make it require that `type` has an `add` method?  I need my SparseMatrix to be able to work with not only numbers and strings, but with other kinds of addable things too, even other matricies.

I would also be using it in my `mul` and `sub` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just do it based on the presence of a method - the types would have to implement a common interface or superclass. For example:

```
public interface Addable<T>
{
    T add(T lhs, T rhs);
}
```

Then:

```
public class SparseMatrix<T extends Addable<T>>
```

Of course you can't make existing types (numbers, strings) implement that interface - you'd have to write your own applicable wrapper type.

Comment: Is there even just a way where I can call the method, even if that would mean my class thows an error if it doesn't have it?  I guess I'll just use the interface thing and define wrappers, if I can't figure something else out.

Comment: @AJMansfield: You could use reflection, but that would be both slow and lose compile-time safety. If you want to execute code dynamically, you really want a dynamic language...

Comment: The problem with using a different language is that this program is for school.

Comment: @AJMansfield: I would ask your supervisor/tutor/whatever what is expected in this situation then.